# Spring load time weaving

Tags: spring, hibernate, configurable, load-time-weaving

After 12 hours of trying I don't seem to be able to get Spring *load time weaving* working on Tomcat.

- Spring 4.2.1
- Hibernate 4.3.11
- Tomcat 8.09

I am trying to get an `@Entity` autowired.

The `weaver` output always says:

```
not weaving 'mypackage.MyEntity'
```

unless I also use a `@Configuration` annotation on it. It will then weave but I get back A `SPRIGNCGLIB` proxy where all the properties are `null`.

If I remove the `@Configuration` annotation (I don't think it should be there anyway) then I don't get any weaving and `@Autowired` property is always `null`.

This is my configuration:

*applicationContext-beans.xml*

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />
<context:spring-configured />
<context:load-time-weaver />
```

*classes/META-INF/aop.xml*

```
<aspectj>
 <weaver options="-Xreweavable">
    <include within="my.package.*"/>
</weaver>
<aspects>
    <aspect name="org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AbstractInterfaceDrivenDependencyInjectionAspect"/>
</aspects>
```

*MyEntity.java*

```
package my.package;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Configurable
public class User {

    private Encrypter encrypter; // THE CLASS I WANT INJECTED

    @Autowired
    public void setEncrypter(Encrypter encrypter) {
        this.encrypter = encrypter;
    }
}
```

*context.xml*

```
<Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"/>
```

The Tomcat `lib` folder has (I am not sure it needs both of these):

- spring-instrument-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
- spring-tomcat-weaver-2.5.6.SEC03.jar

The apps `WEB-INF/lib` folder has:

- aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar
- spring-aop-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
- spring-aspects-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar

I have tried starting Tomcat with

`-javaagent:D:/my/path/to/server/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/lib/spring-instrument-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar`

but it didn't help and according to the [Spring LTW documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-aj-ltw) the `context.xml` fragment is the preferred way to do this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why on earth d you have a 2.5.6 jar in your path? You are mixing different versions of a framework don't ever do that... Also remove the `aop.xml` as Spring already provides one that includes the needed aspects, you are also referencing the wrong one here (the base class not the actual aspect). Last thing to say  load-time weaving and `@Configurable` are different beasts (although one extends the other). You want to inject dependencies into non managed beans, you should be able to do that without `<context:load-time-weaver />`.

Comment: You need [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-atconfigurable) of the reference guide.